Bluetooth AssociationRequest does not display device, but system Bluetooth pairing does
My Android app has a companion device which functions as expected.  However, one user reports that when the dialog opens to choose the companion device, which is invoked when AssociationRequest  is called, no device is listed.  If they use Bluetooth pairing found in Android Settings, however, the device does show up.
The device was previously paired to the app on another tablet, so I know that the BluetoothLeDeviceFilter should allow the device.
Why would the device appear in Android's system Bluetooth pairing, but not in the companion device pairing in the app?

Thanks to this answer on another question, I was able to determine that it is necessary to enable location on the device, which resulted in my BTLE companion device showing up in the dialog box.
